# I just installed bash on windows. When I use sudo, sudo hangs

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-10

I know on linux when you use sudo, it wants a password.

Things I have already tried:

if i type sudo apt-get install g++ and hit enter, the cursor goes to the next line and no output happens. I thought the issue might have been apt-get, so i tried that without sudo, and got the error saying i might not be root. so that is working.

i tried typing sudo, hit enter, cursor goes down to the next line and nothing.

i can type in my password and it isn't ecnrypted. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

ok so moments after I typed this up, sudo said it couldn't resolve host name and gave me the password prompt. Is installing packages.